# XML file with two stylesheets - button to apply different xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file with two XSL stylesheets: A.xsl and B.xsl

A.xsl is the main stylesheet (it is the first stylesheet that has to be applied at the beginning) and B.xsl must be applied only if the user clicks on a button in the A.xsl stylesheet.

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="A.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="B.xsl"?>
```

This is the button that should apply B.xsl to the same xml page.

A.xsl

```
<a href=""> Button </a>
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using the `onClick` function from JS?

Answer (score 0):

XSL doesn't have "buttons" it is a transformation only language. To do what you are asking would require Javascript and possibly server-side interation that would all be entirely dependant on the output of `A.xsl` and whatever generated HTML you are using.